# MYSQL SUM functionality to total rows' 'value' in table groups by a 'key' column

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Quick question, on SQL SUM()

I need to totalise the values of a row in a table , grouped by another column.
So if I have something like the following and turn it into the below.
I know you can do

```
SELECT SUM(value) WHERE key = 'ONE'
SELECT SUM(value) WHERE key = 'TWO'
...
```

But I want to do (if possible) both in a single query. Reason being I don't know if the table results are going
to be ONE or ONE/TWO or ONE/TWO/THREE, etc etc etc. So basically I want to do a SUM for each key type

```
key - value
-----------------
ONE - 3
TWO - 2
ONE - 3
ONE - 1
TWO - 6
```

Result I'm looking for.

```
ONE - 7
TWO - 8
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add a column preferably the `KEY` column, use `AGGREGATE` function `SUM` and grouped them by `KEY`

```
SELECT `key`, SUM(value) totalValue
FROM table Name
GROUP BY `key`
```

Comment: @user1160629 just be careful when using aggregate functions :)

Comment: Careful for? A quick few tests and I get the results I expected.

Comment: you need to be careful when specifying columnNames in the `GROUP BY` clause especially in MySQL, it doesn't generate an error but produces invalid result. hmm i'm trying to give you examples. i'll be back :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT key, SUM(value) FROM table GROUP BY key;
```

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the correct answer then, please. Regards